# Quantlib FixedRateBond Cashflow Memory Leak

Tags: memory-leaks, quantlib

When I extract and iterate over the cashflows in a fixed rate bond, Valgrind reports a memory leak. I am using the following code:

```
FixedRateBond fixedRateBond(
        settlementDays,
        faceAmount,
        fixedBondSchedule,
        std::vector<Rate>(1, couponRate),
        ActualActual(ActualActual::Bond),
        BusinessDayConvention ::Unadjusted,
        redemption,
        issueDate
);

vector<boost::shared_ptr<CashFlow>> cashFlows = fixedRateBond.cashflows();

for (size_t i=0; i != cashFlows.size(); ++i) {
    cout << "Date: " << cashFlows[i]->date() << " Amount: " << cashFlows[i]->amount() <<endl;
}
```

Edit: Looks like it's an OSX issue as the same code doesn't raise any issues when run in Linux. For posterity, here is the report I was getting on OSX:

```
==62096== 148 (80 direct, 68 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 170 of 208
==62096==    at 0x1001F8EA1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==62096==    by 0x102D3D4A2: __Balloc_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==62096==    by 0x102D3DDEB: __d2b_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==62096==    by 0x102D3A443: __dtoa (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==62096==    by 0x102D6307A: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==62096==    by 0x102D8C35C: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==62096==    by 0x102D705A8: _vsnprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==62096==    by 0x102D70607: vsnprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==62096==    by 0x102D60AB1: snprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==62096==    by 0x102ACD752: std::__1::num_put<char, std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::do_put(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, std::__1::ios_base&, char, double) const (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==62096==    by 0x102AB3B33: std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(double) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==62096==    by 0x10000A2D1: main (main.cpp:31)
```

Comment: I don't see how, as both `vector` and `shared_ptr` manage the stored memory correctly.  Do you have more details on what valgrind reports?

Comment: I do, but it seems like it's a OSX issue as I just ran similar code on Linux without any messages from Valgrind. If you still want the reports I can provide them?

Comment: Weird. It seems it's not even the QuantLib code: it's in `operator<<(double)`, after the call to `amount` has completed and when the result is being printed. I agree, I'd attribute it to some kind of OS X issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to OS X as the issue does not occur on Linux and as (the always helpful) Luigi states is not in QuantLib code itself.